# Find MAC address using VB6

Tags: macos, vb6

I want to find the MAC address of network adopter, I have a working code too but my problem is it only works if IP addres is enabled otherwise it won't get the address is there any solution to find MAC address even if IP Enabled is false
if its possible update me with sample code

Here is my code to find MAC

```
Dim myWMI As Object, myObj As Object, Itm

Set myWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set myObj = myWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM " & _
                 "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration " & _
                 "WHERE IPEnabled = True")
For Each Itm In myObj
Dim macme As String
Dim NewMac As String
macme = Itm.MACAddress
NewMac = Replace(macme, ":", "")
Text1.Text = NewMac
    Exit For
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Querying the heavyweight WMI service is not the best choice for application programs.  It is a convenience feature meant only for admin scripting.  The service could be disabled or even uninstalled on older versions of Windows.

Instead you can go directly to the source.  The [GetAdaptersInfo function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917(v=vs.85).aspx) is one of the more obvious candidates.

Using this involves more code than can be conveniently inlined here.  Look for the many examples of use in VB6 posted with working source code at more programmer-friendly sites that permit uploaded attachments.

No matter how you go about it the value of doing this is questionable anyway.  Many integrated network adapters allow users to insert their own MAC Address values anyway.  Quite a few PCs today rely on USB network adapters that are not even plugged in all the time and may get swapped around between devices.